# Git push to azure websites with submodule

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

So far, I've been publishing a site to Windows Azure Websites via Git without any problems. But today we added a submodule to our project and Azure didn't seem to like working with submodules.

The build fails because my app depends of the submodule and Azure sees an empty folder instead of the submodule code.

Any ideas?

Comment: This thread has information on this topic: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/101

Comment: I configured my repo to be public but Kudu isn't initializing it (I think it's not executing the 'git submodule update').. do you know if Azure's Kudu is updated to support this feature?

Comment: Hmmm, as I look at this, I think that the change ended up not being made. But note that we have a new feature coming up (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks) which will let you write whatever logic you want.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Is this resolved now? I have a tricky one where the submodule actually has a submodule, so 'git submodule init' may need to be called a few times.

Comment: @tofutim The issue was recently resolved in the Kudu sources (see that issue), but the fix is not live on Azure yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudu is enabling using git sub-module now

Comment: Great, I'm not interested anymore but thanks anyway. Perhaps you can explain a little more how to use it? :)

Comment: no need more explanation, when your repository contains a sub-module , AzureWebsite Kudu will pull it as part of your repository normally, you don't have to do anything else

Comment: what happens if your git submodule server requires credentials? Is there a way to pass that information? E.g. in case of VSTS

Comment: Exactly @sasha.sochka, I've been running into this issue with submodules, private repos as npm packages, etc. Azure needs a way to create and use an SSH key configured through the Web Portal or some other global means for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah, also wish to extend instructions to be more clear how to use it. However not sure it will help in my case, cause npm deletes some modules during deploy and I forced to run `npm update` manually every time I deploy: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45656121/630169