# Deployment from Github to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, github

When trying to set up a deployment from Github to Azure we get an error about updating submodules. We clone the repo from github to local and run the same command `git submodule update --init` it successfully updates the submodules.

The error is the following:

> "ERROR: Repository not found.\nfatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access
>   rights\nand the repository exists"

I own the repo and it has always been private.

Any ideas?

Comment: working with private linked repositories can be cumbersome. Check the following articles and let me know if they help (note: Kudu is the engine behind Azure Web-/Api-/Mbile- Apps):
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-github
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings
In short: you have to grant the Kudu access to all required repositories.

Answer (score 0):

According the answer of [Git push to azure websites with submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939728/git-push-to-azure-websites-with-submodule), Azure has supported the git submodule without any extra operations.

And by the way, I had a test on my side via [this post](http://blog.joncairns.com/2011/10/how-to-use-git-submodules/) to build a repo with submodule on GitHub, and then deploy to Azure Web Apps. It works fine with submodules on my side and currently I cannot reproduce your issue.

Could you check whether you have selected the correct repo to deploy to Azure.

And you can try to clone your repo to a new one, and remove the submodules, then deploy to Azure, to confirm whether the issue is raised by the submodules?